# How do I set up a id for animations?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to set a id to the animation.

Code:

```
    def on_anim1_start(self, *args):
        self.x = 0
        sound1 = SoundLoader.load("C:\\Users\\kanna\\Music\\OpenCity1.mp3")
        sound1.play()

    def on_enter(self):
        self.label1.opacity = 0
        animation = Animation(d=3) + Animation(d=4, opacity=1) + Animation(d=5) + Animation(d=4, opacity=0)
        animation.bind(on_start=self.on_anim1_start)
        animation.start(self.label1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can use the Inclement's answer with the below answer. So I can ensure you that it works.

```
def on_anim1_start(self, *args):
    self.x = 0
    sound1 = SoundLoader.load("C:\\Users\\kanna\\Music\\OpenCity1.mp3")
    sound1.play()
def on_enter(self):
    self.label1.opacity = 0
    animation = Animation(d=3) + Animation(d=4, opacity=1) + Animation(d=5) + Animation(d=4, opacity=0)
    animation.bind(on_start=self.on_anim1_start)
    animation.start(self.label1)
```

### Changing the code slightly works for me:

```
def on_anim1_start(self, *args):
    self.x = 0
    sound1 = SoundLoader.load("C:\\Users\\kanna\\Music\\OpenCity1.mp3")
    sound1.play()
def on_enter(self):
    self.label1.opacity = 0
    @@your_anim = Animation(d=4, opacity=1)
    your_anim.bind(on_start=self.on_anim1_start)@@
    animation = Animation(d=3) + **your_anim** + Animation(d=5) + Animation(d=4, opacity=0)
    animation.start(self.img2)
```

### Note: Remove the asterisk(*) and at(@) before running.

```
[@@] means added code.  
[**] means edited code.
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't, the Animation doesn't have an id property or accept an id argument. Why do you want to?

Comment: Hello sir, @inclement I need `id` for the sound when the second animation plays

Comment: No, you don't. This looks like an XY problem - what is the actual issue you're trying to resolve?

Comment: I have 4 sequential animations When the second sequential animation starts I need the sound to play. How to do that?

Comment: Then bind your `on_anim1_start` to the `on_start` event of the second animation. Probably `Animation(d=4, opacity=1, on_start=self.on_anim1_start)` works. But even if it doesn't, you could just do `your_anim = Animation(d=4, opacity=1)` then `your_anim.bind(on_start=self.no_anim1_start)`.

Comment: Sir @inclement I have a sequential animation i can't add an another animation

Comment: Nor do you need to, the code I suggested is fully compatible with your creating a sequential animatino.